# API to map a location/place to an event?

Tags: web-services, api, rest, geolocation

Are there any REST services out there that allow to map a location (lat/lon) to an ongoing event? Ideally it would be an API that takes as input

- location / place
- datetime

and outputs an ongoing event at that place/time.

Something like:

```
40.829527,-73.926722 ---> Google Places API: Yankee Stadium
   add datetime information ---> Event service: U2 Concert
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if someone has built this already but you could build it pretty easily using the Foursquare API:

Start by using Search Venues to return venues based on lat/long input.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

Once you have a bunch of VENUE_IDs for nearby venues you can query those venues for their event aspect.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/events